# How to reinitialize a camera object after is has been released outside of onCreate

Tags: android, camera

I am using the camera flash for a Morse code application. I create a new camera object when the class is created. The user has a button which is used to reset and also release the camera when required (If they want to stop the light Morse sequence prematurely).

The problem is that when they hit the reset button because the activity is not created or loaded again the camera never get reinitialized - this is a problem because the method of the class that it is calling is used by another class and releases the camera when it is has completed it's function. I am not sure how to structure the code in a way that allows me to do this.

I am wondering if anyone has any advice/suggestions in how to achieve this?

```
 //Camera object being declared
 Light light;


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity__morse);

    //Camera object being initialized
    light = new Light
 }

  //Reset   user pressed a button
  public void reset(View view)
     {
         light.release();
     }

  //Releasing the camera
  public void release() {

    if(camera != null)
    {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't initialize the camera in onCreate.  Do it in onStart, and release it in onStop.

Comment: That done the trick, thank you. I was trying to do the release operations in the on Pause which was not working and totally forgot about implementing on Start or on Stop. I really appreciate your help, thank you.